# Изменение громкости mp3 в Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, mp3

Воспроизвел `*.mp3` через `ctypes`. Нужно изменить громкость. Как это реализовать стандартными средствами python?

```
def mciSend(s):
    i = ctypes.windll.WINMM.mciSendStringW(s, 0, 0, 0)
    if i != 0:
        print "Error %d in mciSendString %s" % (i, s)

def playMP3(mp3Name):
    mciSend("Close All")
    mciSend("Open \"%s\" Type MPEGVideo Alias theMP3" % mp3Name)
    mciSend("Play theMP3")

def Play(event):
    playMP3("e:/01.mp3")
```

Comment: Зависит от того как именно воспроизвели

Comment: Добавил Код, как воспроизводил.